# Direction API - Trip duration of the same route

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

The Google Direction API return the trip duration of the best route,
instead of the best is possible to have a specific route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `alternatives` parameter (*and set it to `true`*) so that you get multiple/alternative routes, each with its own duration.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters

Comment: Thanks! But i want the duration of the same specific route every time , not alternative route and not the fastest or shortest route.
Is possible?

Comment: Yes, i've tryed but waypoints needs to be setted manually, right?
There are a method to transform "steps" in waypoints?
or something similar

Comment: @Tomma5o what are the criteria that would define the route you want to target ?

Comment: For how waypoints are passed see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Comment: The flow is:
-> make an ajax call with standard param: origin: "foo" destination:"bar"
-> maps suggest for example 3 routes
-> the user select 1 of the suggested routes.
How can i save locally the params needed so that the next ajax call retrive the duration of the user's selected route?

Comment: @Tomma5o don't you have access to the duration of each route from the first ajax call ?

Comment: Yes but after the user choose the preferred route, i don't want google suggest another time the routes without traffic, i want in any case the user's selected route.

Comment: @Tomma5o if you add a `departure_time`  all routes (*the alternative as well*) will have a `duration_in_traffic` property.